# Batch to add file to desktop for all new user accounts

Tags: windows, command-line, boot, batch, automation

I'd like to find a way through a batch file to place an specific file (.doc) at the desktop of all existing users and those who create an account for the first time. I've been able to do it for all existing users (one by one on each account), but I'm having trouble to figure out what to do for newcomers. (Currently running Win 7)

So far, I've got this code from another user

copy name.doc "%allusersprofile%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\" /Y

And I've been able to make a .bat that works the way I want it but only on the current user account

In regards of the command written above:

1. When launched it says ''Access Denied'', would it be possible somehow to make it work even when launched from a non-administrative account?
2. It doesn't solve the issue regarding the launch of this .bat for all new user accounts.

Comment: I answered based on placing a document on everyone's desktop. The question seems to flip between placing a document on the desktop and executing a batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desktop for newly created user profiles in Windows is a copy of the "Default User" desktop.

This is located at C:\Users\Default\Desktop. Anything placed in this location will be copied to the desktop of any newly created user profiles.

If you need to place something here, you will need to be logged in with an account that has administrator access -- regular users cannot make changes to this folder as it affects all new user profiles created on a machine.

The path specified in your question ("%allusersprofile%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\") is entirely different. This is the Startup folder for all users (existing or new -- anyone who logs in). Anything placed in this folder will automatically be executed when anyone logs in. This location can also only be modified by an administrator as it affects all users who login the system.

I apologize -- surprisingly, I could not find much Microsoft documentation that addresses this at this detail, but I did find the following which describes the "Default User" and "All Users" profiles.

http://tutorial.wmlcloud.com/windows_7/Managing-Windows-7-in-a-Domain---Understanding-User-Profiles-(part-1)---Standard-Profiles---Roaming-Profiles.aspx